# I got Error : Property 'BrowserProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: next.js, ethers.js

```
 import ethers from "ethers";
 import { Web3Provider } from "@ethersproject/providers";;
 
 declare global {
   interface Window {
     ethereum?: Web3Provider;
   }
 }
 
 export default function Home() {
 
   let signer = null;
 
   let provider; 
   if (window.ethereum == null) {
     console.log("metamask not installed")
   else {
     provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
     }
 return (
     <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen">
       <div className=" border-red-600 border-2 p-2">Connect Wallet</div>
     </div>
   )
 }
```

I was fallowing ethers.js docs about connecting to ethereum  and got Error about `Property 'BrowserProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof import(...)` . How can i solve it?

I want to connect metamask in Next.js(tsx) project

i read v6 has changed using 'provider' but i couldn't understand.